# expo build:web docker cannot find correct entry point

Tags: node.js, react-native, docker, expo

NOOB to building an expo web app. I’m trying to build a docker container with my expo web app. After I run “expo build:web” and the build successfully finishes, I get a run error when I try to execute.

I have a custom entry point defined in my app.json: “entryPoint”: “./index.js”,

When I run the app in the docker container and connect to http://localhost:19006 I get:

```
./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../App'
```

I can see the entry point defined in the “asset-manifest.json” file. But I don’t know the steps to call that as my starting point and why it’s trying to use “../../App” instead.

Here is my Dockerfile if it helps:

```
FROM node:12.20.2 as build

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

ARG PORT=19006
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT 19001 19002

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm -g npm@latest expo-cli@latest sharp-cli

RUN mkdir /opt/web && chown node:node /opt/web
WORKDIR /opt/web
ENV PATH /opt/web/.bin:$PATH
USER node

COPY package.json ./
COPY .env.production ./.env
COPY ./private ./private

RUN yarn install --silent
RUN ls -al

WORKDIR /opt/web/app
COPY ./web-build .
RUN ls -al

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["web"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

In my package.json file, I had the line:

```
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
```

I changed it to:

```
"main": "index.js",
```

This worked in yarn start mode but not in production so I never gave it another look.

I also had to change the docker file a little by using "serve":

```
FROM node:12.20.2 as build

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

ARG PORT=19006
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT 19001 19002

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm -g npm@latest expo-cli@latest serve

RUN mkdir /opt/web && chown node:node /opt/web
WORKDIR /opt/web
ENV PATH /opt/web/.bin:$PATH
USER node

COPY package.json ./
COPY .env.production ./.env
COPY ./private ./private

RUN yarn install --silent
RUN ls -al

WORKDIR /opt/web/app
COPY ./web-build .
RUN ls -al

CMD ["serve","--no-port-switching","-p","19006"]
```